# Response Optimization for lm()

Tags: r, lm

I had a lm model but I don't know how to optimize the response.

eg.

```
model <- lm(data, formula = z ~ a + b + c + d +..)
```

(combination of attribute and variable predictors, z is variable response)
Say I want to minimize z to zero and want to have a set of values for predictors.

I had used Minitab before and it has Response Optimizer for Regression. Is there any similar functions for R?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, more clarity is needed for us to answer your question. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and refine your question.

Comment: Guess this post can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454770/maximize-nonlinear-regression-function-in-r?rq=1

Comment: Hi Felipe, thanks for sharing the link. It helps me to understand much more. But my lm model has categorical predictors (factors). It seems optim cannot work with factor predictors as I always get errors since my par is list i.e. optim(par = list, ...). I cannot find any useful answers online. Any suggestion?